# Swift - Update UITextView with string using IBAction without deleting old string

Tags: string, swift, append, uitextview

I am trying to send and update strings inside a UITextView using and IBAction button.

the code below works fine however, every time i push the button the old text is replaced with the new one. What I am trying to do is to always append the text to the exiting one.

Any Idea?

```
@IBAction func equalPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        var resultString:String = "new string"

        textView.text = resultString.stringByAppendingString("= " + resultLabel.text! + ";")

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know how to append strings, but you're doing it two different ways. The `stringByAppendingString(_:)` method is fine, but Swift's `+` operator is clearer. I'd rewrite your existing method as follows:

```
@IBAction func equalPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let resultString = "new string"
    textView.text = resultString + "= " + resultLabel.text! + ";"
}
```

Then, to append the text rather than replace it, it's a simple change of including the old value in the new one:

```
textView.text = textView.text + resultString + "= " + resultLabel.text! + ";"
```

Or, using the `+=` operator (`x += y` is short for `x = x + y`):

```
textView.text += resultString + "= " + resultLabel.text! + ";"
```